# Puppeteer: remove attribute

Tags: javascript, dom, puppeteer

```js
<div>
  <button class="button--primary button--filled" disabled="disabled" data-action="publish">
   <span class="ButtonText">Save and publish
   </span>
  </button>
</div>
```

I have the above button element on browser and I couldn't enable it unless I remove the `disabled="disabled"` attribute. Setting another value didn't help.

Is there a way to remove the attribute completely? (Using `page.$eval()` is preferable)

Comment: This could be done with javascript when you run puppeteer. See the docs: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.5.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute

Comment: "Setting another value didn't help." -- it's good to show the code for this so others know what you tried exactly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, you can use [`Element.removeAttribute(attrName)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute):

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.1.0

const html = `
<div>
  <button class="button--primary button--filled" disabled="disabled" data-action="publish">
   <span class="ButtonText">Save and publish
   </span>
  </button>
</div>
`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const sel = '.button--primary.button--filled[disabled="disabled"]';
  const el = await page.$(sel);
  await page.$eval(sel, el => el.removeAttribute("disabled"));
  console.log(await el.evaluate(el => el.outerHTML));
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Output (with `disabled="disabled"` removed):

```html
<button class="button--primary button--filled" data-action="publish">
   <span class="ButtonText">Save and publish
   </span>
  </button>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding (to a 2-year-old question). I hope it will be useful for whoever comes across this question.